# #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Fala pessoal estou tendo problemas para criar uma chave estrangeira em outra tabela... Está dando este erro:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails....
```

Segue o comando que estou fazendo para criar chave estrangeira:

```
ALTER TABLE cad_cadastro_cliente_acb ADD FOREIGN KEY (ID_SERV_CLIENTE_FK) REFERENCES cad_fluxo_servico(ID_CAD_FLUXO_SERVICO)
```

Segue as tabelas que criei no banco:

```
CREATE TABLE cad_cadastro_cliente_acb(
ID_CLIENTE_ACB int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT, 
TIPO_PJ_PF_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(50), 
NOME_RAZAO_SOCIAL_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(100), 
CNPJ_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(50), 
CPF_CAD_ACB varchar(50), 
NOME_CONTATO_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(100), 
NOME_SOCIAL_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(100),
COMO_CONHECEU_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(10),   
ENDERECO_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(100), 
COMPLEMENTO_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(100), 
BAIRRO_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(100), 
CIDADE_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(100), 
CEP_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(100), 
UF_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(100), 
EMAIL_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(50), 
CONTATO01_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(15), 
CONTATO02_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(15), 
OBS_CLIENTE_ACB varchar(300),
ID_SERV_CLIENTE_FK INT(10) NOT NULL, 
USER_CAD_LOG varchar(20),
DATA_CAD_USER datetime,
PRIMARY KEY (ID_CLIENTE_ACB)
)ENGINE = innodb;



CREATE TABLE cad_fluxo_servico(
ID_CAD_FLUXO_SERVICO int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
SETOR_SERVICO varchar(20),
TITULO_SERVICO VARCHAR (100),
DESCRICAO_SERVICO VARCHAR(500),
RESPONSAVEL_SERVICO VARCHAR (50),
USUARIO_CAD varchar (50),
DATA_CAD_USER datetime,
PRIMARY KEY (ID_CAD_FLUXO_SERVICO)
)ENGINE = innodb;
```

Comment: Faça uma query verificando se todos os valores existentes em `cad_cadastro_cliente_acb.ID_SERV_CLIENTE_FK` efetivamente existem em `cad_fluxo_servico.ID_CAD_FLUXO_SERVICO`. O erro pode ser devido a uma referência indevida.

Comment: Tente `SELECT cad_cadastro_cliente_acb.ID_CLIENTE_ACB, cad_cadastro_cliente_acb.ID_SERV_CLIENTE_FK 
FROM cad_cadastro_cliente_acb LEFT OUTER JOIN cad_fluxo_servico ON (cad_cadastro_cliente_acb.ID_SERV_CLIENTE_FK = cad_fluxo_servico.ID_CAD_FLUXO_SERVICO)
WHERE cad_fluxo_servico.ID_CAD_FLUXO_SERVICO IS NULL`

Comment: Opa amigo retornou um valor um valor sim... MAS a tabela cad_fluxo_servico está vazia

Comment: Se retornou um valor então este valor tem que existir na tabela `cad_fluxo_servico` para que possa ser criada a chave estrangeira. Você pode limpar a tabela `cad_cadastro_cliente_acb` criar a chave estrangeira e depois inserir os dados.

Comment: funcionou... valeu meu amigo... tive que limpar a tabela